# The remote module has not been cached locally

Tags: typescript, deno

When I import a package in my deno application I get this error:

```
The remote module "https://deno.land/std@0.85.0/http/server.ts" has not been cached locally
```

It seems like its downloading the package every time I'm running the. project, how can I cache the package?

```
import {serve} from "https://deno.land/std@0.85.0/http/server.ts";
export const server = serve({port:  3005});
```

Comment: can you please show a [mre] of your code and how you start it. Ususally you don't have to do anything special. On first start you can see that the packages are downloaded and after that it's cached. What happens if you explicitely cache it: `deno cache https://deno.land/std@0.85.0/http/server.ts`?

Comment: you didn't answer my last question in the comment above. And also, is this problem specific to that module does it happen with other modules as well? I can't reproduce it here.

Comment: @jps oh thanks, it worked by the command cache, I don't know why it does not do this automatically, the libraries must be cached manually in. my system

Comment: Which Deno version (`deno --version`) do you use? In case it's a older version, does `deno upgrade` help? And do you use the VSCode Deno plugin? There was an [issue](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/issues/24) that should be solved now. Update that as well.